# Appropriate Partition size for dual booting Ubuntu 13.04 with Windows XP MCE

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I own an old **HP Pavilion a1220in** PC. The problem is that it came with just **80gb SATA**.
I have **Windows XP MCE SP2** pre-installed on it. But I want to dual boot it with **Ubuntu 13.04**. I checked online for solutions, and I did find the method for it. It doesn't seem much difficult, but the Partition size thingy is confusing me. I have no idea what would be appropriate partition size for both XP and Ubuntu, so that both of them can run whenever I want.

I have only **23gb's left in my C-Drive**. Another Partition already exists, that Windows made itself, about 7gb. There is a Recovery folder with a lock symbol on it. I already have the Recovery Discs, so I don't think that the Partition is necessary.

**The results for installation of Ubuntu did not tell what would be the appropriate size for Partitions. Will Ubuntu's installation do it itself or is it necessary for me to set it manually? And will this installation affect my Windows installation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XP does not have any internal tools for partitioning, so use gparted from liveCD to shrink it, but reboot XP immediately to let it run chkdsk.

XP supposedly will work in 10 to 15GB, but you need to have about 30% free space in the NTFS partition for Windows to work well. At 10% free it just about stops working and defrag may take forever.

How much space is used in your XP isntall? And can you houseclean some data?

Ubuntu can install in 10GB, some have installed in 5 or 6GB but have to continuously houseclean. If installing Lubuntu or Xubuntu less space is needed and if an older computer Lubuntu may be a better choice. You also need swap equal to RAM if you have 2GB or less of RAM. If you only have 512GB or RAM then you need swap to be 2X RAM and cannot really run full Ubuntu and have to use Lubuntu.

Comment: I do not know how much space Windows XP takes while installing as it came with my PC pre-installed. I could only find a Recovery Partition (D-drive) of 7.3gb and a WINDOWS folder in the C-drive which shows "Size: 9.61gb" and "Size on Disk: 7.15gb". 
Sorry for such a noobish answer, I am not that good with PC's.
I do not prefer Xubuntu, Lubuntu or Kubuntu personally, as I like GNOME 3.
My PC Specs: 1.5gb RAM, 80gb SATA (24gb's free) Pentium-4 3.06ghz processor.

Comment: If your Windows is 9.6GB and you have used 7, it is just about full. You actually may want to increase it a bit. You should just be able to install Ubuntu into the unallocated. If you have one available primary partition it will auto install with / (root) and swap.

Comment: Thanks. But in the installation phase, it must be setting some Partition size for both by default. Should I leave it that way or make some changes?

Comment: That is your choice. The auto options are to make it easier for a new user. But I prefer to know exactly what it is doing and since DOS days I have done partitioning, so I always manage my own partitions. I use gparted and then use Something else to choose the partitions I have already created.

Comment: Thanks. i will install Ubuntu in the Unallocated, and I think will leave Windows to where it's at. I am thinking of sizing Ubuntu's partition to 10GB. Should that be fine?

Comment: Hey, I have used disk cleanups and CCleaner to cleanup my PC. Also, I have deleted many things from my PC. Now I have 40gb of space on my HDD. So what should I keep the Partition size for Ubuntu. I will leave Windows as is. But I think that in the Partition, 7.3 GB is recovery partition whereas the whole C Drive is the Windows partition. What should I do?